# Sorting A List From Least to Greatest Without list.sort( )

Tags: python, list, sorting

As an intellectual challenge, I'm trying to do what is described in the title. I am stuck, and wondering if anyone had any helping ideas..?

```
def main():
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,63,3]
    sort(my_list)

def sort(my_list):
    n=0
    m=1
    for number in my_list:
        if my_list[n] < my_list[m]:
            my_list[n] = my_list[n+1]
        n+=1
        m+=1
    print my_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As is this opens it up for someone to provide a sort implementation, at which point that would seem to cease to be an intellectual challenge.  It would be more useful to say what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many sorting algorithms, such as `bubble`, `quick sort` and so on, and here is a reference http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/, you can implement any of them according to the descriptioin.

The following is bubble sort

```
def main():
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,63,3]
    sort(my_list)

def sort(my_list):
    size = len(my_list)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size-i-1):
            if(my_list[j] > my_list[j+1]):
                tmp = my_list[j]
                my_list[j] = my_list[j+1]
                my_list[j+1] = tmp
    print my_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope helps!

Answer (score 1):

*Most* python implementations use the [`mergesort` algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)<sup>1</sup>.

A quick google search will turn up an implementation, but the algorithm is simple enough that it's worth trying to code it yourself.

<sup><sup>1</sup> (Actually, they use Tim sort which is a hybrid between mergesort and insertion sort ...)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(L):
    newlist = []
    for x in range(len(L)):
            newlist.append(min(L))
            L.remove(newlist[x])
    return newlist
```